# Show that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln|x+1|}{x^2+1}dx= \frac\pi8 \ln2$ using a suitable substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried $\tan x=t$ and got $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}\ln|2| - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{t\cdot\sec^2{t}}{1+\tan^2x} dt$. Either the substitution is wrong or I don't know how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\tan u$ then $\mathrm dx=\sec ^2 u\,\mathrm du$ .
$$ \int^\frac{π}{4}_0 \frac{\ln(|1+ \tan u|)}{1+ \tan ^2 u} \sec^2 u\,\mathrm du = \int^\frac{π}{4}_0 \ln(|1+\tan u|)\,\mathrm du$$
Substituting $\frac{π}{4} - u$ in place of $u$,
\begin{gather*}
\int^\frac{π}{4}_0 \ln\left|1+\tan\left(\frac{π}{4}-u\right)\right|\,\mathrm du = \int^\frac{π}{4}_0 \ln\left|\frac{2}{1+\tan u}\right|\,\mathrm du\\
=\int^\frac{π}{4}_0 \ln2\,\mathrm du - \int^\frac{π}{4}_0 \ln|1+\tan u|\,\mathrm du=\int^\frac{π}{4}_0 \ln|1+\tan u|\,\mathrm du
\end{gather*}
On looking at the last two equalities we get the result.

Comment: You can use \ln to produce $\ln$.